# A longer arrow in a diagram

Tags: diagrams, arrows

I created the following diagram:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ccc}
&& A  \\
&\rotatebox{45}{$\longrightarrow$}& \rotatebox{90}{$\subseteq$}\\
B&\subset& C
\end{array}
\end{equation}
```

But the diagonal arrow looks to short. I tried to use `\xrightarrow{\hspace*{1cm}}`, but it does not help: the second row of the diagram becomes too high.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Can you please post a drawing of what you actually want to achieve (maybe hand-written and scanned, or made as a sketch in some painting software or such)? From your question it seems to me that you try to find a complicated way to do something for which good LaTeX packages exist.

Comment: To the downvoter: If you have to downvote a newcomer's question, then at least have the dignity to comment on what do you think is wrong with it.

Comment: Thanks Yo! I will add a hand-written drawing tomorrow, since I don't a scanner handy. But basically, I want the arrow to go from B to A, and want it to start closer to B and to end close to A (then it is in the formula generated by the code I put in the original post).

Comment: @yo' to be fair the down vote might have just been finger trouble...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this sort of diagram nicely with `tikz-cd`.  The documentation is on CTAN [here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd).

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ccc}
&& A  \\
&\rotatebox{45}{$\longrightarrow$}& \rotatebox{90}{$\subseteq$}\\
B&\subset& C
\end{array}
\end{equation} 
and now with tikz-cd
\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzcd}
    & A \\
    B \arrow[ru] \arrow[r,phantom, "{\subset}", description] 
    & C          \arrow[u,phantom, "\rotatebox{90}{$\subseteq$}", description]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you, Thruston! (1) is exactly what I have, and (2) is exactly what I need. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome.  And welcome to Tex.SE!

Comment: Hi Thruston! I am about to submit a paper to arxiv, but arXiv's automated TeX processing has failed to process the diagram. Here is the log: 

! Arrow direction argument must contain only the characters l, r, u or d.
\tikzcd@parse ...only the characters l, r, u or d}
\fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \tikzc...
l.171 B \arrow[ru] \arrow
[r,phantom, "{\subset}", description]
? 
! Emergency stop.
\tikzcd@parse ...only the characters l, r, u or d}
\fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \tikzc...
l.171 B \arrow[ru] \arrow
[r,phantom, "{\subset}", description]
! ==> Fatal error occurred

Do you know if this can be fixed?

Comment: @Alex I don't know arXiv - but [their help](http://arxiv.org/help/mathjax) pages indicate that they only support a subset of LaTeX, or they might be using out of date versions of tikz-cd.  You could try the other solutions here, or ask for advice from the arXiv support team.  Alternatively you might be able to make your diagram into an external standalone graphic file and import that using `includegraphics`.  Good luck.

Comment: As of today (Apr. 26, 2016) arxiv is still using texlive 2011, and apparently [this only works for 2013 or later](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230099/how-to-label-an-arrow-in-a-commutative-diagram#comment543538_230099).  One suggestion I saw that could work is the ugly creation of the CD on its own, and then inclusion in the final document by `includegraphics`.

Answer (score 4):

Borrowing some code from [LaRiFaRi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/216042/4427)

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzset{
  symbol/.style={
    draw=none,
    every to/.append style={
      edge node={node [sloped, allow upside down, auto=false]{$#1$}}}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzcd}
    & A \\
    B \arrow[ru] \arrow[r,symbol=\subset]
    & C          \arrow[u,symbol=\subseteq]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a much neater way of doing it.  Why isn't `symbol=` a standard part of `tikz-cd`?  Perhaps it should be included in the next release.

Comment: @Thruston That would be a nice addition indeed!

Answer (score 3):

A solution with the  `psmatrix` environment, from `pst-node`. You can compile it with `pdflatex`, provided you use the compiler switch `--enable-write18` (MiKTeX) or `-shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX):

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,11pt, pdf]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{pst-node}

\newpsobject{ncemptyline}{ncline}{linestyle=none}
\newcommand*\ncsubset[2]{\ncemptyline{#1}{#2}\ncput[nrot=:U]{\subset}}
\newcommand*\ncsubseteq[2]{\ncemptyline{#1}{#2}\ncput[nrot=:U]{\subseteq}}
\newcommand*\ncsubsetneq[2]{\ncemptyline{#1}{#2}\ncput[nrot=:U]{\varsubsetneq}}
\newcommand*\ncvarsubsetneq[2]{\ncemptyline{#1}{#2}\ncput[nrot=:U]{\scalebox{1}[-1]{$ \varsubsetneq $}}}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\[ \psset{nodesep=2pt, linewidth=0.6pt, rowsep=6mm, colsep=8mm}
\begin{psmatrix}
& [name=A] A \\
[name=B] B& [name=C] C\\
\ncline[arrows=->]{B}{A}
\ncsubset{B}{C}\ncsubseteq{C}{A}
\end{psmatrix}
 \]
 \end{document}
```

[image]