# How to label an arrow in a commutative diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm writing my thesis using LaTeX. I need to add a commutative diagram with labels on arrows. Let me say that I'm writing my text in Italian using the `babel` package.

Here a minimal example to understand the problem:

```
\documentclass[oneside,italian]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd} A \arrow[rd] \arrow[r, "\phi"] & B \\ 
                                              & C 
\end{tikzcd} 
\end{document}
```

The problem is that if I don't use the package `babel` the code doesn't create any errors. 
If I insert babel I get this message error:

> Undefined control sequence.
>   ... \arrow[r,"\phi"] & B \ & C
>   \end{tikzcd}
>   The control sequence at the end of the top line of your
>   error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g.,
>   `\hobx'), type`I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox').
>   Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Moreover, if I cancel the code `"\phi"` all works using `babel` or not.
Any suggestion?

I've tried to upgrade the version of the package `tikz-cd` but nothing changes.

Comment: Your code runs fine for me.

Comment: What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: The code works well on TeXlive 2014 and 2013, but it does not work on TeXlive 2012, it stops with an error: `! Arrow direction argument must contain only the characters l, r, u or d.` Is this among the error messages you see? Maybe it's time for an update, then.