# Automatically stretching non-default arrows in tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

Can I make a non-standard arrow stretch automatically? I'm hoping not to have to apply a `\scalebox` manually every time.

Approach to generating non-standard symbols is taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/216027/how-to-draw-this-diagram).

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}  
\tikzset{
    symbol/.style={
        draw=none,
        every to/.append style={
        edge node={node [sloped, allow upside down, auto=false]{$#1$}}}
    }
}

\begin{document} 
\[
    \begin{tikzcd}[row sep= 2ex, column sep=0.8em]
        aaaaa \arrow[d, equals] & bbbbb \arrow[d, equals] \\
        c \arrow[symbol={\neq}]{r} & d
    \end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add the `\not` instead of `\ne`.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}  
\tikzset{
    not/.style={
        every to/.append style={
        edge node={node [sloped, allow upside down, auto=false]{$\not{}~$}}}
    }
}

\begin{document} 
\[
    \begin{tikzcd}[row sep= 2ex, column sep=0.8em]
        aaaaa \arrow[d, equals] & bbbbb \arrow[d, equals] \\
        c \arrow[equals,not]{r} & d
    \end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just a consideration: I like `xy` package (used to create `commutative-diagram`) an old package that I believe that is still used sometimes. It is true: the code is cryptic but it is fascinating because with the option `cmtip` you can create to a 60% commutative diagram similar to `tikz-cd`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[cmtip,all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@R=1pc{
aaaaa \ar@{=}[d] & bbbbb \ar@{=}[d] \\
c \ar@{=}[r] \ar@{}[r] |{/} & d}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The advantage is the equal arrow does not have the vertical line in the tail and in the tip. Look the output of the `@user237299` and zoom in the figure. To put the negation equal arrow you can use `\ar@{}[r] |{/}` code (or insert `{/}`, or any other symbol e.g. `{\backslash}`). You can decrease or increase the distance of the rows using the parameter `@R=1pc`.

Definitely if you look at the commands of `tikz-cd` and `xy` package there are many analogies.

If you want to decrease the length of the equal arrow you can use `\xymatrix@R=1pc@C=.5pc` (for example) (R=row and C=column).

Comment: Thanks, that's quite a general solution.

Comment: @mjc Thank you for your edit...I have a very poor English language.