# How to write this full notation in LaTeX

Tags: amsmath, mathtools

Please tell me how can I write this in LaTeX. I tried to do with array and `\underset` but was not satisfying
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tikz-cd` supplemented with the [lovely answer by LaRiFaRi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/216042/4427) and a couple of small tricks.

1. The spacing between first and second column is reduced.
2. The superscript to `\mathbb{R}` at the top has been given zero width, so the balancing is better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/216042/4427
\tikzset{
  symbol/.style={
    draw=none,
    every to/.append style={
      edge node={node [sloped, allow upside down, auto=false]{$#1$}}}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=small]
&[-1.5em] & \mathbb{R}^{\mathrlap{n}} \\
\mathbb{R}^m \arrow[r,symbol={\supset}] &
U \arrow[r,"f"] &
V \arrow[r,"g"] \arrow[u,symbol={\subset}]&
\mathbb{R}^k \\
& a \arrow[u,symbol={\in}] \arrow[r,mapsto] & b \arrow[u,symbol={\in}]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]