# Align problems when using XY-pic

Tags: xy-pic

I want to draw this diagram using XY-pic.[image]
But I have trouble with the position of the arrows. [image]

Any help would be appreciated.
The codes are as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

$$\begin{gathered}
\xymatrix{
    \beta(X)\subset Q^{F(X)}\ar[rr]^{\bm{f}^{**}} & & Q^{F(Y)}\supset\beta(Y)\\
    X\ar[u]^{\bm{e}} \ar[rr]^{f} & & Y\ar[u]^{\bm{g}} \\ 
}
\end{gathered}$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to SE. You don't explain what trouble you think you have, and you don't show any LaTeX code that people could test or correct. Please provide a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Comment: I have trouble when adding pictures.

Comment: I don't understand your answer: I was asking about *code*, not *picture*. And you seem to have included a picture just fine in your question.

Comment: Show the code used to generate the second image.

Comment: Your code compiles correctly and gives a result that is very close to the original image. Could you be clearer about what you don't like with "the positions of the arrows"? Also, would you accept a solution that doesn't use `xy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the particular case you can make the objects in the first row larger by using phantoms.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix@C+2em{
  \hphantom{Q^{F(X)}\subset{}}\beta(X)\subset Q^{F(X)}
    \ar[r]^{\bm{f}^{**}} &
  Q^{F(Y)}\supset\beta(Y)\hphantom{{}\subset Q^{F(Y)}}\\
  X\ar[u]^{\bm{e}} \ar[r]^{f} & Y\ar[u]^{\bm{g}} \\ 
}
\]

\end{document}
```

1. Never use `$$` in LaTeX
2. Avoid superfluous columns, it's better to increase the column separation
3. Use `cmtip` or the arrow tips are awful
4. Is there a reason why just one label is not `\bm`?

[image]

The same with `tikz-cd` and the nice code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/216042/4427

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{bm}

\tikzset{
  symbol/.style={
    draw=none,
    every to/.append style={
      edge node={node [sloped, allow upside down, auto=false]{$#1$}}}
  }
}


\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=4em]
  \beta(X) \arrow[r,symbol=\subset] &[-3.5em]
  Q^{F(X)} \arrow[r,"\bm{f}^{**}"] &
  Q^{F(Y)} \arrow[r,symbol=\supset] &[-3.5em]
  \beta(Y)
  \\
  X \arrow[u,"\bm{e}"] \arrow[rrr,"f"] &&& Y\arrow[u,"\bm{g}"]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your so nice answer!

Comment: @mio I wish I had `xy` or `tikz-cd` when I was studying the Stone-Čech compactification! :-)