# How do I recreate this commuting square in latex?

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I'm trying to recreate the following diagram:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try to use a 3x3 table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `matrix` for a naïve solution, but you should realize that `\subset` and `\cup` are generally not the same symbol with a rotation.

I suggest to rotate `\subset`, but also to modify the vertical spacing.

A different solution uses `tikz-cd`; I show also how to change the spacing in a simpler way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for the first solution
\usepackage{tikz-cd} % for the second solution

% for the second solution, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/216042/4427
\tikzset{
  symbol/.style={
    draw=none,
    every to/.append style={
      edge node={node [sloped, allow upside down, auto=false]{$#1$}}}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
\begin{matrix}
N & \subset & M \\[2ex]
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\subset$} &&
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\subset$} \\[2.5ex]
Q & \subset & P
\end{matrix}
\]

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
N \arrow[r,symbol=\subset] & M \\
Q \arrow[r,symbol=\subset] \arrow[u,symbol=\subset] &
P \arrow[u,symbol=\subset]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1em,column sep=1em]
N \arrow[r,symbol=\subset] & M \\
Q \arrow[r,symbol=\subset] \arrow[u,symbol=\subset] &
P \arrow[u,symbol=\subset]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I am happy there is an answer that includes spacing. I was also concerned about \cup vs. \subset. When you say "generally not the same", does that mean there are situations where they are the same?

Comment: @Infimum That depends on the font used for math symbols.

Answer (score 5):

A matrix works

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

$\begin{matrix} N&\subset&M \\ \cup&&\cup \\ Q&\subset&P \end{matrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 2):

A very short code with `pstricks`:

```
     \documentclass[a4paper,11pt, pdf]{article}

    \usepackage{pst-node}

    \newpsobject{ncemptyline}{ncline}{linestyle=none}
    \newcommand*\ncsubset[2]{\ncemptyline{#1}{#2}\ncput[nrot=:U, npos=0.45]{ ⊂}}

    \pagestyle{empty}

    \begin{document}

    \[ \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep = 0.1, colsep = 0.3]
    N & \subset & M \\
    \rput{*90}{\subset} & & \rput{*90}{\subset} \\[1ex]
    Q & \subset & P
    \end{psmatrix} \]

    \end{document}
```

[image]