# Achieve desired alignment of arrows in tikz-cd diagram

Tags: nodes, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I want to add to add the supersets of the sets `U_\tau` and `V_\tau` (respectively for `\pi`) to the following tikz-cd diagram

[image]

I managed to achieve the following result

[image]

Latex code:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\AAA}{\mathbb{A}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Bl}{Bl}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{tikzcd}[/tikz/column 1/.append style={anchor=base east}, /tikz/column 2/.append style={anchor=base west}]
        S \supset U_\tau \arrow[r, "\varphi_0"] \arrow[d, "\tau", "\sim"'] & U_\pi \subset T \arrow[d, "\pi", "\sim"']\\
        \Bl_{(0,0)}(\AAA^2) \supset V_\tau \arrow[r, "\epsilon"] & V_\pi \subset \AAA^2
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

I would like the arrows to be typeset as in the first diagram, i.e. going from `U_\tau` to `V_\tau` (respectively for `\pi`). I know i can move them manually, but i can't seem to get rid of the rotations.
Is there a way to tell tikz-cd that i want the arrows to start centered on `U_\tau` and end centered on `V_\tau` (respectively for `\pi`)?

Comment: Get rid of the optional argument to `tikzcd`, the `anchor=base east` is changing how the arrows point, the default is to have vertical arrows, then you can manually shift them left or right as needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add “symbol” arrows, plus a trick to make the first column right aligned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,calc}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/216042/4427
\tikzset{
  symbol/.style={
    draw=none,
    every to/.append style={
      edge node={node [sloped, allow upside down, auto=false]{$#1$}}}
  }
}

\newcommand{\AAA}{\mathbb{A}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Bl}{Bl}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}[
]
  \mathmakebox[\widthof{$\Bl_{(0,0)}(\AAA^2)$}][r]{S} \arrow[r,symbol=\supset] &[-1.5em]
  U_\tau \arrow[r, "\varphi_0"] \arrow[d, "\tau", "\sim"'] &
  U_\pi \arrow[r,symbol=\subset] \arrow[d, "\pi", "\sim"'] &[-1.5em]
  T 
\\
  \Bl_{(0,0)}(\AAA^2) \arrow[r,symbol=\supset] &
  V_\tau \arrow[r, "\epsilon"] &
  V_\pi \arrow[r,symbol=\subset] &
  \AAA^2
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No tricks are needed, here is a pure `tikz-cd` solution:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\AAA}{\mathbb{A}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Bl}{Bl}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{tikzcd}[
        /tikz/column 1/.append style={anchor=base east, column sep=0pt, inner xsep =0pt}, 
        /tikz/column 3/.append style={column sep=0pt}, 
        /tikz/column 4/.append style={anchor=base west, column sep=0pt, inner xsep =0pt}
        ]
        S \supset & U_\tau \arrow[r, "\varphi_0"] \arrow[d, "\tau", "\sim"'] & U_\pi \arrow[d, "\pi", "\sim"'] & \subset T \\
        \Bl_{(0,0)}(\AAA^2) \supset & V_\tau \arrow[r, "\epsilon"] & V_\pi & \subset \AAA^2
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]