tikz-cd: vertical $\in$ instead of arrow
My code is below:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\[\begin{tikzcd}
    A & B & C \\
    & {\textnormal{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(A,B)} & {\textnormal{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(A,C)} \\
    & g & {f \circ g}
    \arrow["g", from=1-1, to=1-2]
    \arrow["f", from=1-2, to=1-3]
    \arrow[from=1-2, to=2-2]
    \arrow[from=1-3, to=2-3]
    \arrow["{f_*}"', from=2-2, to=2-3]
    \arrow[maps to, from=3-2, to=3-3]
\end{tikzcd}\]

I obtained the following diagram:

I want to input $\in$ sign vertically twice for $g$ and $f \circ g$.
If there is a way to do this, please let me know.

Off-topic: (i) Instead of writing \textnormal{Hom}, I would specify \DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom} in the preamble and write \Hom in the body of the document. (ii) Writing ..._\mathcal{C} isn't particularly robust; try ..._{\mathcal{C}} instead.

Is the symbol defined by \vin what you're looking for?

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage{graphicx}   % for '\rotatebox' macro
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\vin}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\vin@\relax}}
\newcommand{\vin@}[2]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\m@th#1\in$}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$u \vin v \quad \scriptstyle u \vin v \quad \scriptscriptstyle u \vin v$
\end{document}


If that's the symbol , the following might be a way to achieve your typesetting objective.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\DeclareMathOperator' macro
\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}
\newcommand\HomC{\Hom_{\mkern1mu\mathcal{C}}}

\usepackage{graphicx} % for '\rotatebox' macro
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\vin}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\vin@\relax}}
\newcommand{\vin@}[2]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\m@th#1\in$}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
    A & B          & C          \\
      & \HomC(A,B) & \HomC(A,C) \\
      &     \smash[t]{\begin{array}[b]{@{}c@{}}
                          \vin \\ g 
                      \end{array}}
          & \smash[t]{\begin{array}[b]{@{}c@{}}
                        \vin \\ f \circ g 
                      \end{array}} 
    \arrow["g", from=1-1, to=1-2]
    \arrow["f", from=1-2, to=1-3]
    \arrow[from=1-2, to=2-2]
    \arrow[from=1-3, to=2-3]
    \arrow["f_{\!*}"', from=2-2, to=2-3]
    \arrow[maps to, from=3-2, to=3-3]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}


I believe that the style conceived by LaRiFaRi should become part of tikz-cd.
The relevant answer is at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/216042/4427
Here is the code.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/216042/4427
\tikzset{
  symbol/.style={
    draw=none,
    every to/.append style={
      edge node={node [sloped, allow upside down, auto=false]{$#1$}}}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
  A \arrow[r,"g"] & B \arrow[r,"f"] \arrow[d] & C \arrow[d] \\
  & \Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(A,B) \arrow[r,"f_*"'] & \Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(A,C) \\[-1em]
  & g \arrow[u,symbol=\in] \arrow[r,mapsto] & f \circ g \arrow[u,symbol=\in]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}

Notes

I prefer arrows next to their source, so I don't have to count.
\textnormal{Hom} is wrong.
No need for braces around “complex” nodes.
_{\mathcal{C}} is the correct syntax.


